# ImportPSModulesFromPath doesn't add anything to the Modules collection

Tags: powershell, module

I've got a Powershell module which I'm needing to load into a Runspace for use by different threads. I understand that defining a SessionState allows me to load modules in that can then be accessed by the runspace:

```
$SessionState = [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState]::Create()
$SessionState.ImportPSModulesFromPath("$filepath\Validation Library.psd1")
$runspacePool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool($SessionState)
```

The problem is that I can't seem to get `ImportPSModulesFromPath` to do anything - it doesn't return any errors, yet the `$SessionState.Modules` collection is always empty, and my Runspace keeps returning errors saying it can't find the functions in the module, even though they're defined properly in the psd1 and do work if I load normally using `Import-Module`.

The psd1 file contains the module definition pointing to a psm1 file in the same folder (I get the same behaviour when pointing directly to the psm1)

Answer (score 0):

After lots of searching and testing, I was unable to determine anything wrong with the script - until I closed and reopened my Powershell session.

Though I had been taking care to dispose and remove variables I thought were being used, I had been running the same scripts with the same variables repeatedly, and so something incorrect had been stored down into one of my variables, causing the module load to fail.

Running the same script in a new session showed that the module was loading successfully.